# DisplayPort error on Thinkpad for Ubuntu

Tags: thinkpad, external-monitor

My Thinkpad L480 constantly throws an error when connecting external monitors to the docking station. I have to open and close the lid of the notebook repeatedly to get a signal.

It throws the following error. Not sure what it means:

```
kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 000000005b62a483 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 000000005b62a483 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
```

Any idea what I could do? It does not happen under Windows...

Comment: What is the docking station make and model? Also, do you use the DisplayLink Manager software for Linux?

Comment: DisplayLink(R) USB Graphics Software for Linux is free software and they make a version for Ubuntu.  https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: @mondotofu it is a Thinkpad Pro Docking Station

Comment: That's the kind of docking station that I have, too for my Thinkpad T480.  I recommend that you install the Ubuntu software and see if that makes for a smoother experience.

Comment: have you had a chance to try the DisplayLink software?

Comment: Not yet, I managed to work around the problem by switching to Wayland. There the problem does not occur.

Comment: Yes, Wayland is the future of display server. Glad you resolved it.